# Pull specific values from array to calculate

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables. Table 1 is a schedule which holds weekly games. Table 2 is a separate table where you select just one team from the scheduled games for a week.
I am trying to get the difference in the score for the game that I chose a team for. So for a specific week, there are 13-16 games. I select 1 team from one of those games. If the team I pick wins, the result is the difference in the score. So if my team wins and the score is 27-10, I show 17 point. I have tried every way I can think to get this, but the best I seem to come up with is that it will calculate the last game of the week only, not the specific game that my team is involved in. The gameID is the key between both tables. Is it possible to do this? I thought by grabbing the values based on gameID from the array it would match it to the gameID associated with the selection from table 2.I am able to display the correct team, week by week, but not get the point differential for that specific game. Any ideas?

```
<?php
for($wk=1;$wk<=17;$wk++){
    $allScoresIn = true;
    $currentDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //get array of games
    $games = array();
    $sql = "select s.*, (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > gameTimeEastern or DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > '" . $cutoffDateTime . "')  as expired ";
    $sql .= "from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule s ";
    $sql .= "where s.weekNum = " . $wk . " ";
    $sql .= "order by s.gameTimeEastern, s.gameID";

    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $e = 0;
        $homePtDiff = 0;
        $visitorPtDiff = 0;
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $games[$row['gameID']]['gameID'] = $row['gameID'];
            $games[$row['gameID']]['homeID'] = $row['homeID'];
            $games[$row['gameID']]['visitorID'] = $row['visitorID'];
            $games[$row['gameID']]['homeScore'] = $row['homeScore'];
            $games[$row['gameID']]['visitorScore'] = $row['visitorScore'];
            $games[$row['gameID']]['homeDiff'][$e] = $row['homeScore'] - $row['visitorScore'];
            $games[$row['gameID']]['visitorDiff'][$e] = $row['visitorScore'] - $row['homeScore'];
            $homePtDiff = $row['homeScore'] - $row['visitorScore'];
            $visitorPtDiff = $row['visitorScore'] - $row['homeScore'];
            if ((int)$row['homeScore'] != NULL && (int)$row['visitorScore'] != NULL) {
                $scoreEntered = TRUE;
            }else{
                $scoreEntered = FALSE;
            }
            if ((int)$games[$row['gameID']]['homeScore'] > (int)$games[$row['gameID']]['visitorScore']) {
                $games[$row['gameID']]['winnerID'] = $row['homeID'];
            }else if ((int)$games[$row['gameID']]['homeScore'] < (int)$games[$row['gameID']]['visitorScore']){
                $games[$row['gameID']]['winnerID'] = $row['visitorID'];
            }
            else{
                $games[$row['gameID']]['winnerID'] = NULL;
            }
            $e++;
        }
    }
    $sqlinner = "select * from " . DB_PREFIX . "pickmargin where weekNum = " . $wk . " and userID = " . $x . ";";
    $queryinner = $mysqli->query($sqlinner);
    if ($queryinner->num_rows > 0) {
        $resultinner = $queryinner->fetch_assoc();
        $currentPick = $resultinner['pickmargin'];
        $currentGameID = $resultinner['gameID'];
        $hidePicks = $resultinner['showPicks'];
        $marginPts = 0;
        $y_value = $x_value-1;
    } else {
        $currentPick = 'TBD';
    }
    if ($currentPick == $games[$row['gameID']]['homeID']){
        $marginPts = (int)$games[$row['gameID']]['homeScore'] - (int)$games[$row['gameID']]['visitorScore'];
    }
    else{
        $marginPts = (int)$games[$row['gameID']]['visitorScore'] - (int)$games[$row['gameID']]['homeScore'];
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, I mean, you're already getting the points in the variables `$homePtDiff` and `$visitorPtDiff`, but you're not using them

Comment: That was one of my attempts, but if I use those variables at the bottom so that $marginPts would equal the respective value, it doesn't work....

Comment: Oh, ok, I see you're attempting to use `$row` out of the context of the `while`, which isn't right. At the end of the code, you should probably be using `$currentGameID` instead of `$row['gameID']`, like this: `if ($currentPick == $games[$currentGameID]['homeID']){` (apply it also for the lines below it)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. I am getting better results now and with a little more work on scenarios, should be perfect.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad it worked

Comment: Hi @JerryH Im also working on personalizing the PHP NFL pickem script I was just curious if you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: @Timothy Coetzee - Yes I have everything working now! Post on the forum and I will share what I have